# "Floating point exception" in code that contains no floats

Tags: c

In this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    uint64_t bignum = 600851475143;
    int is_prime = 0;
    uint64_t result = 0;
    uint64_t i = 0;
    uint64_t j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < bignum; i++) {
        if (bignum % i == 0) {
            is_prime = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    is_prime = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (is_prime) {
                result = i;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The largest prime factor of the number %lu is %lu.\n", bignum, result);

}
```

when compiling with:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g 3.c -o 3 -lm
```

I get a "floating point exception" upon running the resulting executable. There are no floating point numbers in the code. What is going wrong here, and what do I need to do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Divide by 0 is reported as a "floating point exception". Don't ask me why.

You're dividing by 0 in at least two places. Note that the modulo operator `%` counts as division.

Comment: It's funny that floating point numbers *don't* generally even cause this error.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Yeah. Division by zero causes infinity in `float`s.

Answer (score 2):

On the first iteration of the loop, `i` is 0, so `bignum % i` is a division by 0, which is what causes the floating point exception.  The same happens with `j` in your inner loop.

Since you're testing for primality, dividing by 0 or by 1 doesn't make sense, so start with 2.  Also, you should stop at `sqrt(bignum)`.

```
uint64_t limit = sqrt(bignum);
for (i = 2; i < limit; i++) {
    ...
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
```

Comment: Also, there is no point in testing 4, 6, 8, etc.
Do a test for 2, then make your for-loop: `for(i = 3; i < limit; i+=2)`, effectively testing 3, 5, 7, 9, etc....